# ORacle ADF af:table column separation

Tags: css, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I am working in Oracle ADF, there is a table with 20 columns, I like to separate 5 columns in each section. After 5th column there is button, by clicking that button I could able to see 2nd 5 columns, likewise every 5th column there is a button and after clicking that button I need to expand that section. Is there any option to place vertical button between 2 columns in adf table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about having a vertical button inside a table , but you can have a button on the toolbar facet whose code code would look like

```
 <af:commandButton text="Show Next Column" id="cb2">
      <af:setPropertyListener from="#{viewScope.counterValue eq null ? 1 : (viewScope.counterValue + 1)}"
                              to="#{viewScope.counterValue}"
                              type="action"/>
    </af:commandButton>
```

and for your column's rendered property you can have

```
rendered="#{viewScope.counterValue gt 0}"
```

This code would display next column on each click. You can change the condition depending upon your problem set .. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the  component to add 5 columns each time when you click the button.
  --Peddi

Answer (score 0):

My response may seem not related, but have you ever thought about using a listview instead of a table to render 20 columns? A table with 20 columns is huge...and may not be that user-friendly. Well using a list view like this:
[image]

You can fill in the 20 attributes(columns) in the white space of each list item. 
This is just a suggestion, and 20 attribute in a list view may still be huge. Just trying to give new UI design ideas.

Thanks~

P.S. the listview doc is here:

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_listView.html

And the pic is also from that doc~